# A problem with a proof that $L^{p_{2}}\subseteq L^{p_{1}}$ for $1\leq p_{1}\leq p_{2}\leq\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In a functional analysis course I saw a claim that for $1\leq p_{1}\leq p_{2}\leq\infty$we
have it that $L^{p_{2}}\subseteq L^{p_{1}}$

I have a few problems with the proof given, and I would appreciate
some clarifications. The proof given is (my comments are in $[]$):

Acuatlly, we will prove that 
$$
id:\,(C([a,b]),||\ldotp||_{p_{2}})\to(C([a,b]),||\ldotp||_{p_{1}})
$$

is continuous.

Let $f\in C([a.b])$. fix $0<\alpha<1$ and define:

$$
A=\{x\in[a,b]\mid|f(x)|>1\}\,,\, B=\{x\in[a,b]\mid\alpha\leq|f(x)|<1\}\,,\, C=\{x\in[a,b]\mid|f(x)|<\alpha\}
$$

Then: 
$$
\int_{a}^{b}|f|^{p_{1}}=\int_{A}|f|^{p_{1}}+\int_{B}|f|^{p_{1}}+\int_{C}|f|^{p_{1}}
$$

$$
\leq\int_{A}|f|^{p_{2}}+\int_{B}1+\int_{C}\alpha^{p_{1}}
$$

$$
\leq||f||_{p_{2}}^{p_{2}}+\mu(B)+(b-a)\alpha^{p_{1}}
$$

[those $3$ line are denoted as $(1)$]

[I don't think that the next line follows from what's done already]
$$
||f||_{p_{1}}^{p_{1}}\geq\int_{B}|f|^{p_{2}}\geq\alpha^{p_{2}}\mu(B)
$$

[denote the above as $(\star)$]

$$
\implies\mu(B)\leq\frac{||f||_{p_{2}}^{p_{2}}}{\alpha^{p_{2}}}
$$

set this in $(1)$ and get 
$$
||f||_{p_{1}}^{p_{1}}\leq||f||_{p_{2}}^{p_{2}}+\frac{||f||_{p_{2}}^{p_{2}}}{\alpha^{p_{2}}}+(b-a)\alpha^{p_{1}}
$$

Set 
$$
\alpha=||f||_{p_{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

$$
\implies||f||_{p_{2}}^{p_{2}}+||f||_{p_{2}}^{\frac{p_{2}}{2}}+(b-a)\alpha^{p_{1}}
$$

And we see the required continuity.

My question are:

1. How did we get the first inequality in $(\star)$ ?
2. Why can we set $\alpha=||f||_{p_{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ ? i.e why
   $0<\alpha<1$ ?
3. Why what we want to prove follows from the continuity mentioned,
   and how did it follow from the last line ?
4. Why did we star with $f\in C([a,b])$ ? I thought the elements
   of $L^{p}$ just have integrability constraints on them, not continuity
   constraints (I guess that this relates to the last question)
5. Doesn't the last line just say that $\int|f|^{p_{1}}<\infty$ and
   that's what we want to prove ?

P.S I realize those are more questions here then a usual post, I will
give $150$ point bounty to the accepted answer.

Comment: For question 1. you have
$$
\|f\|_{p_1}^{p_1}~\geq~
\int_B|f|^{p_1}~\geq~
\int_B|f|^{p_2}
$$
and the last inequality follows from the fact that $|f|\leq1$ in $B$, so $|f|^{p_1}\geq |f|^{p_2}$.

As to the equation after $(\ast)$, haven't you mistyped $p_2$ in place of $p_1$ in the numerator of the rhs?

Comment: @AndreasT - thanks, I understand question 1 now. It does seem like a typo since I can't deduce the inequality from that line, but it is set with $p_2$ in the following lines, so I can't say what was the original meaning. This is how its written in my notebook..

Comment: I too thinkg that $\|f\|_{p_2}^{\frac 12}<1$ does not necessary hold. Anyway, if we agree of the mistyped $p_2$, then the following inequality can be worked into
$$
\|f\|_{p_1}^{p_1}\big(1-\textstyle{\frac{1}{\alpha^{p_2}}}\big)
~\leq~
\|f\|_{p_2}^{p_2} + (b-a)\alpha^{p_1}
$$
which already proves that if $\|f\|_{p_2}<\infty$ so is $\|f\|_{p_1}<\infty$. And 'till here you didn't need continuity, but just $L^{p_2}$-integrability.

The continuity might be needed to prove the continuity of the map $id$.

Comment: Not an answer to your questions, but that "proof" is pretty fucked up. The proper proof uses Hölder's inequality.

Comment: I agree with Daniel.   I don't think that trying to decipher this text  worth be worth either your time or mine. But I want to say that you can label displayed formulas with `$$ x=y \tag{1} $$`.